# find files which are not currently in use

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, find, lsof

I'm trying to archive some older files, but don't want to touch all the files which are currently in use. What's the best way to ask `find` to exclude "in use" files?

Right now I'm working on this command, but I'm asking if there's something better (my `find` expression is slightly more complicated, but take it as an example)

```
find /tmp/ -type f \( -exec fuser -s {} \; -o -print \)
```

Comment: Echo `lsof` output to a file or environment variable. Archive only those files which are not in the `lsof` output.

Comment: @boardrider thank you for your suggestion, but your solution seems more complex then mine. It involves at least a `grep` filter between the `find` command and the archive one. In my solution I could perform any command through a `-exec` expression inside the `find`.

Comment: I think your solution gives the files `in use` while your question asked for files `not in use.`

Comment: @boardrider no it doesn't. The `-o` means if a file is in use, do nothing, but if a file is not in use (`fuser` returns with `1`), then go on with the expression which is `-print`

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to **is there anything slightly less complicated?** is **no**.

I tried your example and it did the job...

```
$ find . -type f \( -exec fuser -s {} \; -o -print \)
./a_temp_file
./another_temp_file
$ ( sleep 10  ) > file_open_for_10_secs &
[2] 31969
$ find . -type f \( -exec fuser -s {} \; -o -print \)
./a_temp_file
./another_temp_file
$ 
[2]+  Done                    ( sleep 10 ) > file_open_for_10_secs
$ find . -type f \( -exec fuser -s {} \; -o -print \)
./file_open_for_10_secs
./a_temp_file
./another_temp_file
```

Obviously you should probably also look for files last written to over a certain length of time ago as you don't want to muck about with temporary files that are in use as part of a script, but otherwise I don't see a simpler solution.